# getting a Blank Page after deploying React app on GitHub Pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

https://github.com/Cyoger/personal-website

this is my repo, i have tried changing package.json homepage URL and a lot of other stuff but it still shows a blank page, is there any fix for this?

Comment: GEThttps://cyoger.github.io/static/js/main.7d1a8e30.js

GEThttps://cyoger.github.io/static/css/main.88336c8f.css
[HTTP/2 404 Not Found 24ms]

Comment: so is there a problem with those files?

Comment: Do you have your index.html committed - Follow link - https://pages.github.com/
I have done mine here https://santoshkaranam.github.io/ and repo is here - https://github.com/santoshkaranam/santoshkaranam.github.io

Comment: name of repo and index.html must be as mentioned in https://pages.github.com/

Comment: The site seems to work now. Please don't forget a final statement here if your issue has been solved!